# javatrace : addtracehere returns java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, logging, trace

I just started with javatrace from this link http://javatrace.sourceforge.net/user_guide.html. I downloaded the jar file and put java.properties in my classpath. I use eclipse IDE. The first class

```
package JavaTrace;
// Import the class
import org.jtrc.trace.JavaTrace;

import JavaPkg.Pkg2Class;

//import com.jtsimtest.pkg2.Pkg2Class;

/**
 * This class demonstrates the use of 
 * the JavaTrace methods. 
 */
public class SimpleJavaTraceTest
{

    //private static JavaTrace javatrace;
  private static void doNothingReally()
  {
    String aString = "This is a string";
    String hello = " hello world";


    // Here's a trace call
    JavaTrace.addTrace(aString);


    Pkg2Class obj2 = new Pkg2Class();
    int i = 3 + obj2.getTheValue();


    // Here's another trace call
    JavaTrace.addTrace("This is where we are and the value of i = " + i);


  }

  /**
   * The main method.
   * @param ar The passed arguments
   */
  public static void main(String args[])
  {

    // A default trace statement
      JavaTrace.addTraceHere();

      doNothingReally();
  }
}
```

and the other class

```
package JavaPkg;
import org.jtrc.trace.JavaTrace;

/**
 * Another class with trace
 * statements
 */
public class Pkg2Class
{
  /**
   * This method returns a fixed value 
   * of 125.
   * @return The fixed value
   */
    JavaTrace jt;
  public int getTheValue()
  {
    // Add a trace statement
      JavaTrace.addTrace("In the getTheValue() method of Pkg2Class");

    return 125;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){

      Pkg2Class p = new Pkg2Class();
      p.getTheValue();

      JavaTrace.addTraceHere();
  }
}
```

The problem is when I compile it returns

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at org.jtrc.trace.JavaTrace.addTraceHere(JavaTrace.java:164)
    at JavaTrace.SimpleJavaTraceTest.main(SimpleJavaTraceTest.java:45)
```

for both classes.

There is no for loop here but why does it return arrayexception?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by `JavaTrace`. This is the source of the `addTraceHere()` method.

```
public static void addTraceHere() { 
    StackTraceElement ste = thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3]; 
    if(isTraceOn(ste.getClassName())) writeOutput((new StringBuilder(string.valueOf(getLocationInfo(ste)))).append("Trace statement added here").toString()); 
}
```

The important part is `getStackTrace()[3]` which gets the stack trace of the current thread and since you haven't done anything in your code before calling `addTraceHere()` this array may not have 4 elements.

Try to call some methods before calling `addTraceHere()` see if that prevents the exception.

[More details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()) about the `getStackTrace()` method.

Comment: I call this before addTraceHere()                                                               public static void printloop(){
   for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
    System.out.println(i);
   }
  } but still gives me the same error. The link that you provide it doesn't contain the method of addTraceHere. Can you provide the link about addTraceHere()? I dont find any link except this http://javatrace.sourceforge.net/user_guide.html

Comment: The link I've included is for the `getStackTrace()` which mentions that the returned array contains method names (methods that were executed on this thread) so to increase this array's size just call some methods (maybe more then one), also you can call `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` in your code to see if you've reached a size greater then 4. I've got the code that I've posted by decompiling the `JavaTrace` class file.